# Pairing an Apple bluetooth keyboard with a Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

Is there a trick to pairing an Apple bluetooth keyboard with a Windows 7 PC (64 bit)?  It is a Lenovo Q700 using an ioGear USB dongle.  The dongle is functioning fine, but when I turn on the Apple keyboard (which puts it into discoverable mode automatically), Windows cannot find it.

Is there a trick or known incompatibilities with the bluetooth dongle I'm using?

The keyboard can pair fine w/ my ipad, etc.

Comment: have you followed everything here? http://www.tenniswood.co.uk/technology/how-to-pair-an-apple-wireless-keyboard-with-windows-7/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+tenniswood+%28Tenniswood+Blog%29&utm_content=Google+Reader

Comment: @Sandeep - Nailed it.  Feel free to add that as the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The steps listed in this [article](http://www.tenniswood.co.uk/technology/how-to-pair-an-apple-wireless-keyboard-with-windows-7/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20tenniswood%20%28Tenniswood%20Blog%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader) provide details on how to get your keyboard working with Windows 7

From the article:

> If you already have Bluetooth setup on your pc of laptop, simply use the windows default bluetooth wizard…
>
> 1. Turn on wireless keys ON and Bluetooth on PC ON (make sure it’s discoverable)
> 2. Open the ‘Devices and Printers’ panel
> 3. Select ‘Add a device’
> 4. Let it scan for your keyboard, which may come up as just ‘keyboard’ or as an ‘Apple Keyboard’
> 5. Select use your own Passkeys and type in 1111 using your existing keyboard.
> 6. Although it won’t look like it, it will now be waiting for you to enter the same password on your new Apple keyboard (remember to press enter)
> 7. If successful it will prompt that the device is installed and ready to use.

Comment: may I suggest copying the steps here in case the linked page is moved or removed?

Comment: Any suggestions on a program to remap some keys? For example, windows-command key and control key.